# asdf ASDF_DOWNLOAD_PATH: unbound variable for nodejs

Tags: node.js, asdf

when I try to install nodejs 12.13.0 with `asdf install nodejs 12.13.0` I receive `/Users/john.doe/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/bin/install: line 52: ASDF_DOWNLOAD_PATH: unbound variable`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

It can be caused by ASDV v0.7, try running

```
asdf update
```